# LibGDX: Moving text field so it is visible when typing with on-screen keyboard

Tags: keyboard, passwords, libgdx, textfield, android-softkeyboard

I am currently making a login system for a game I am making. I have a "Username" `TextField` and a "Password" `TextField`. When using a mobile device such as Android, I am required to use an on screen keyboard. The thing is that the keyboard blocks the `TextField` box and I can't see it any more when I'm typing. Is there a way to move the `TextField` while the On-Screen Keyboard is being shown?

I have tried several ways but where I am stuck is that there is no way to detect whether the keyboard is on the screen or not. Also, using a pop-up text entering dialog is out of the question since I have a password field and there is no password option for those.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So late to answer, but if helps anyone.

Add a `FocusListener()` to the `TextField` and thus you can listen to the event when the `TextField` is focused (clicked).

Change the camera's `y` position to a number that is around half the screen height by calling:

```
camera.position.set(x, y, z);
camera.update();
```

This will move the screen up and you can now view the things that were blocked earlier by the keyboard.

Comment: A bit late but I can still use it. Thanks for taking the time to answer it anyway!

Comment: :) No problem. Glad you can still use it.

Comment: this is nice, but how do you move the camera back, when for example a user presses the back button? this does not set `focus=false`

Comment: @Green_qaue Yeah I faced that problem too. When the keyboard pops up Android will get the control from Libgdx, so back button cannot be caught. I couldn't get around that issue. What I did was put a big transparent button and listened to its change listener to reset the camera position. Use `stage.unfocusAll()` to unfocus all actors.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by catching the back button. But you need to re-write the android launcher.

Comment: @Green_qaue That's great! I'll try that next time.